# Detect which JPA provider is used based on EntityManager

Tags: jpa

Is there a way to detect which JPA provider is used when only a EntityManager handle is available?

Since EntityManagers are often proxied, looking at the class doesn't work too well. Is there a standard property for this in EntityManager or EntityManagerFactory getProperties map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, no. But you can use the [getDelegate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getDelegate%28%29) method and see what it returns. For Hibernate, it returns the Hibernate `Session` instance, for example. Just getting the name of the class of the delegate returned should give you an idea of the underlying provider.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like a fairly stable approach. I wonder if this will be proxied as well in some cases.